# How do I use the result of a parent key request outside its function

Tags: javascript, firebase

The following gets me the parent key of a child node.
Is there a way to take the result (parent key) outside of the function, like a global variable or something.
I want to be able to call a function that returns me the parent key

This works (returns the parent.key in the console)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
    ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(user.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach((function(child) { console.log(child.key) }));
    });
});
```

This does not work

```
var test;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
    ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(user.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach((function(child) { test = child.key }));
    });
});
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
function f_returnUserDetails(a){
    var key;
    var childData;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                key = childSnapshot.key;
                childData = childSnapshot.val();
                resolve([childData, childSnapshot.key]);
            });
        });
    });
};


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid = user.uid;
    f_returnUserDetails(uid).then((dbItems) => {
        console.log(dbItems[1])
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The test variable is indeed assigned inside the function. The problem is that the `on()` method to fetch from the database is *asynchronous*. This means that the `console.log()` statement *will be executed before* the test variable is assigned.

Consider reading up on, and use a promise approach to achieve what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

You can also use `async` and `await`, which is basically a way to hide `Promise`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thanks @jonasdev, I will have a look at it